# Preferred way to reverse ordering of JSX elements conditionally?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm wondering if there's a best practice way to reverse the ordering of child elements of some component conditionally, I do **not** want to override this using css.

My use case is for a button that can have an icon on one side or the other. What I have currently works:

```
const someFlag = true

  return (
    <div className="parent">
      {someFlag && <img src='A'></img>}
      <button>{"myButton"}</button>
      {!someFlag && <img src='B'></img>}
    </div>
  )
```

but my actual `child{X}` components are a bit more involved so I have some duplicate code, and I also want to guard against future cases where I might have more than 2 children.

I'm thinking of throwing this into an array and reversing based on the flag but I just have no idea what that means for performance, and am having trouble finding relevant results on google

Comment: It's not just reordering, is it? You're also changing the `src`.

Comment: that src will end up being tied to the flag, sorry to not include it in my original post

Answer (score 2):

If your real code is really that simple, I suggest taking advantage of CSS flexbox if you can:

```
<div className="parent" style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: someFlag ? "column" : "column-reverse" }}>
  <img src='A' />
  <button>{"myButton"}</button>
  <img src='B' />
</div>
```

You can extract it into a CSS class as well:

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.parent.reversed {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

```
<div className={`parent ${someFlag ? "" : "reversed"}`}>
  <img src='A' />
  <button>{"myButton"}</button>
  <img src='B' />
</div>
```

Demo of how it would work:

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.reversed {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <p>child 1</p>
    <p>middle</p>
    <p>child 2</p>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="parent reversed">
    <p>child 1</p>
    <p>middle</p>
    <p>child 2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, however I'd like to do this without using css :) Basically I want to keep custom css in my code to an absolute minimum

Answer (score 1):

You can make this element a separate component and just render it like you did. React is also about readability and your code is perfectly readable:

```
return (
  <div className="parent">
    {someFlag && <MyComponent />}
    <button>{"myButton"}</button>
    {!someFlag && <MyComponent />}
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably overkill for most use cases, but you could make a component that flips the order of it's children like this:

```
interface OrderFlipperProps {
    children: React.ReactNode;
    flipped?: boolean;
}

const OrderFlipper = ({ children, flipped }: OrderFlipperProps) => (
    <>{flipped ? Children.toArray(children).reverse() : children}</>
);
```